# Slice an array values less than 85 in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
array(0=>12,1=>34,2=>334,3=>87,4=>75);
```

and what i want is values which is less than 85 in this array. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to do that. Or just a foreach loop filling all values `< 85` in a new array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use PHP's builtin array function [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to handle filtering values based on a custom filtering function.

```
<?php
    function less_than_85($value) {
        return $value < 85;
    }

    $arr = array_filter($arr, "less_than_85");
?>
```

See a live example using your sample input [here](http://ideone.com/76Diva).

Answer (score 0):

you could do a foreach loop over the array with an if statement that unsets the key.

something like

`foreach($array as $k => $v){
if($v>= 85) unset($array[$k]);
}`